# Error with "input file" in Django. Does not recognize the file

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have problems working with django images, when selecting an image in the django manager everything works correctly, but when creating my own form it does not work.

That is, filling the entire form correctly, selecting the file normally, at the time of submitting the form, does not send it and deselects the file you select, and tells me that said field is required. It makes no sense, I select the image, send the form and tell me that the field is required, and the image I chose is deselected.

Here my model:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'course')
    description = models.TextField()
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'get_users')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title', 'created']
```

Here my view:

```
class CourseCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Course
    fields = '__all__'
    template_name = 'courses/course_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <form action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form.as_p }}
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Crear</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
{% endblock %}
```

---

**More explicit example of the problem:**

Fill in the form correctly:

[image]

I click on the "Crear"/Create button, and the following happens:

[image]

It tells me that the field is required and appears in the "I don't choose the file" input, what is happening?

Comment: Show the template. Did you set the enctype on the html form element?

Comment: **OK I did it**

Comment: What is the enctype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django models's fields have `null=False`, `blank=False` by default.

So you need:

```
 image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'course', null=True, blank=True)
```

`blank=True` allow form input to be empty.

`null=True` sets `NULL` on database, basically means empty values are allowed on insert.

It looks like you have also not defined encoding type in your form.

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the default value if the enctype attribute is not specified.

`multipart/form-data` is necessary if your users are required to upload a file through the form.

Enclude `enctype` in your template.

```
<form method="post" action="your action" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Remember to re-run the migration.

Comment: It just doesn't give an error, and when reviewing the media folder, the image is not saved

Comment: So probably issue with file system permission. Does image uploads successfully?

Comment: As for the browser it was loaded correctly, but the same problem that I commented in my question happens, as for file permissions I do not see it necessary, because when I do it from the django administrator everything works, and the images are saved in the folder half

Comment: *Folder media**

Comment: Show templates contents in your question.

Comment: __OK did it..__

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Now it worked, thanks!